# Describing and sketching a set of complex numbers satisfying certain conditions

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to describe and sketch the set of complex numbers satisfying the conditions |z|≥1 and Im(z) > 0.

This is what I have done:

I've said that |z| ≥ 1 is a circle with radius 1 centred at the origin and by having |z| be √(x^2 + y^2) and Im(z) = y, so substituting in to the conditions we get √(x^2 + y^2)≥1 and y > 0.

Then sketching it we have,

[image]

Do the description and sketch look correct for this question?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!